# how to json serialize object contain objects in dot net core web api?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, code-first, asp.net-core-webapi

At web API Dot net core
I have an action that GetById.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Get")]
    public IActionResult Get(long ID)
    {
        ResultResponse oResultResponse = new ResultResponse();
        IActionResult response;
        try
        {
            ContractReleaseRequest result = service.GetByID( ID);
            ;
            oResultResponse.Returned = result;
            oResultResponse.IsSucceed = true;
            oResultResponse.ErrorID = EnumServiceStatus.NoError;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            oResultResponse.IsSucceed = false;
            oResultResponse.ErrorID = EnumServiceStatus.ExceptionError;
            oResultResponse.ErrorMessage = e.Message;
        }

        response = this.Ok(oResultResponse);
        return response;
    }
```

and the model ContractReleaseRequest  is.

```
public partial class ContractReleaseRequest
{
    public ContractReleaseRequest()
    {
        ContractReleaseRequestTranslate = new HashSet<ContractReleaseRequestTranslate>();
        RequestFile = new HashSet<RequestFile>();
    }

    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string RequestNo { get; set; }
    public long? DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string PurchaseOrderNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public long? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public  DateTime RequestDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsSend { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public long? ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public Department Department { get; set; }
    public Contract Contract { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ContractReleaseRequestTranslate> ContractReleaseRequestTranslate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RequestFile> RequestFile { get; set; }
}
```

And the model is

```
using Trio.Contract.Data.Models;
[MapsFrom(typeof(Data.Models.ContractReleaseRequest), ReverseMap = true)]
public class ContractReleaseRequestModel
{
    //public ContractReleaseRequestModel()
    //{
    //  ContractReleaseRequestTranslate = new HashSet<ContractReleaseRequestTranslateModel>();
    //  RequestFile = new HashSet<RequestFileModel>();
    //}

    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string RequestNo { get; set; }
    public long? DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string PurchaseOrderNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public long? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public long? ModifiedBy { get; set; }       
    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public DateTime RequestDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsSend { get; set; }


    [IgnoreMap]
    //[IgnoreMapToAttribute(typeof(DepartmentModel))]
    public DepartmentModel Department { get; set; }
    public ContractModel Contract { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ContractReleaseRequestTranslateModel> ContractReleaseRequestTranslate { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RequestFileModel> RequestFile { get; set; }

}
```

when i call it from post man it return

> Could not get any response
>   There was an error connecting to http://localhost/ContractApi/api/ContractReleaseRequest/Get?ID=1.
>
> Why this might have happened:
>   The server couldn't send a response:Ensure that the backend is working properly
>   Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
>   Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
>   Proxy configured incorrectly Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings > Proxy
>   Request timeout:
>   Change request timeout in Settings > General

when I searched I understand that this error because the main model contain another objects or models and, it cannot serialize them to JSON, But I don't know the solution.
Anyone help me??

Comment: You should Use POCO for serializations. When your Contract object contains ContractReleaseRequest object and vice versa, Newtonsoft generally fails to serialize it due to circular relations.

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: Simply don't serve your entity object. Create a DTO object and convert your entity to DTO. Then return the DTO object. If you verify this will solve your problem I can demonstrate it in an answer.

Comment: i created DTO , and used automapper to map between them ,then it return the same error

  ContractReleaseRequest result = service.GetByID(ID);
 var obj = Mapping.Mapper.Map<ContractReleaseRequestModel>(result);

Comment: Can you update your question with   ContractReleaseRequestModel?

Comment: i added it to the question

Comment: Any other model objects in the ContractReleaseRequestModel contains ContractReleaseRequestModel property?

Comment: Yes , there is relation between them , yes it is something like circular , How can i tell it to take the first level and not go to detailed properties

Comment: @HodaOsama For this error, it seems to be related with **Postman** instead of serialization. try to request this method from web browser, will you get expected result? For this error, try follow open postman-> Settings->General->SSL certificate verification turn off. If there is no such settings, try to download the new [postman](https://app.getpostman.com/app/download/win64), and go to settings-> from file tab.